# Process that can occur in open and closed system

Tags: thermodynamics

I have read [posts](https://www.studysmarter.us/explanations/physics/engineering-physics/non-flow-processes/) where processes like isochoric, adiabatic, isothermal & isobaric processes are considered as non-flow processes. Does this mean that these processes can occur only in a closed system where only non-flow process is possible?

Here is what my current thoughts are on this

**Isothermal process** can occur in an open system if heat is added slowly to the fluid such that the temperature of fluid is almost constant. Done by maintaining a flow rate which allows the heat transfer to be done at infinitesimal difference in temperature.

Similarly since we are considering a control volume (constant volume) **isochoric process** should also be possible even though mass transfer occurs, such as isochoric heat addition.

Although I think **adiabatic process** will be restricted to closed system (non-flow process) since the transfer of mass will result in transfer of heat (to be precise thermal energy).

And I guess **isobaric processes** are also possible in open system as long as pressure is held constant (although flow may not happen due to pressure difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isothermal:  Your reasoning for isothermal seems correct

Adiabatic:  Adiabatic means that the control volume is insulated from actual heat transfer.  Energy transfer  by fluid flow into or out  of the control volume does not constitute flow of heat.

Isochoric:  Isochoric does not seem to apply to an open system unless the average density in the control volume is constant, and the volume flow rates into and out of the control volume are equal.

Isobaric:  This is possible if the pressure inside the control volume is uniform, and equal to the initial pressure; this also goes for the pressures of the inlet and outlet streams.

Comment: So technically all the four process are possible in an open system with flow occurring. And I guess the only way a flow is possible in the isobaric process is by virtue of a change in the volume, so that fluid flows in/out of control volume.

Comment: Only if it is a liquid.  Ir it is a gas, then all that is needed is that the pressure within the control volume is uniform spatially and that is equal to the initial pressure.